# Необходимо удалить элементы после remove(). Без vector, string

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, строки, stl

```
void deleteGaps(char text[])
{
    remove(text, text + strlen(text), ' ');
    ...
}
```

Метод remove() лишь смещает неугодных в конец массива text[].
Необходимо удалить неугодных совсем. Прошу помогите мне, умоляу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить совсем - не получится, это массив, который вы не можете менять просто так. Но если вы имеете в виду получить из С-строки С-строку же без пробелов - то:

```
void deleteGaps(char * text)
{
    *remove(text, text + strlen(text), ' ') = 0;
}
```